# Can I limit the method in Ruby on Rails is POST method only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController 

 def doSomething

 end

 def doSomethingAgain

 end

end
```

Can I restrict the user pass a get method only to doSomething, but doSomethingAgain is only accept post method, can I do so?

Answer (score 5):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController 
  verify :method => :post, :only => :doSomethingAgain

  def doSomething
  end

  def doSomethingAgain
  end

end
```

Comment: You need to use a symbol or a string when passing the action name in `:only`. @Draco I've edited your answer - hope that is OK.

Comment: Note that (as of rails 3.0.3): "verify was removed from Rails and is now available as a plugin"

Answer (score 2):

You may specify in `routes.rb`

```
map.resources :users, :collection=>{
  :doSomething= > :get,
  :doSomethingAgain => :post }
```

You may specify more then one method

```
map.resources :users, :collection=>{
  :doSomething= > [:get, :post],
  :doSomethingAgain => [:post, :put] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here example

```
resources :products do
  resource :category

  member do
    post :short
  end

  collection do
    get :long
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be best off with using [`verify`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Verification/ClassMethods.html#M000383) as Draco suggests. But you could also just hack it like this:

```
 def doSomethingAgain
   unless request.post?
     redirect_to :action => 'doSomething' and return
   end

   # ...more code
 end
```